# How to get title from a website by xpath?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I am playing around with xpath, but have no Idea how to for example get a title from a website using xpath, here is my code but I don't know what to do next...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.cool.de");

$x=new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $x->query("//TITLE");

//...???
```

and print_r($result) shows me only "Object", is there a function like print_r to see what is inside an object so I don't have to guess?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`$result` is a DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

```
echo $result->item(0)->textContent
```

---

**Edit:** xpath is case sensitive - dom nodes must be lower case:

```
echo $x->query('//title')->item(0)->textContent
```

[This](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OkQ3Er) now works

Comment: doesn't work:  PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @qxxx: Then the document has no `<TITLE>` element. XPath is case-sensitive!

Comment: @qxxx: It's possible that DOMDocument corrects that to lower case

Comment: If your using chrome, you can get xpath of almost any element via the developer tools. ctrl+shift+i, elements tab. Find the element you want, right click and get the xpath

Comment: just checked, and you are right! dom converts the tag names to lower case. now it should work.